# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener callback is not called across applications

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, shared-memory

We have `two apps with same sharedUserId and same signature`. So one application can write to others' SharedPreferences without any problem (tested). But the problem is that when `App A writes something to App B's shared preferences,` `OnSharedPreferencesChangedListener's` in App B is not get called. Both apps were running during the test.

Any idea? Thank You.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. I would suggest you to rely on either **Broadcasts**, **FileObserver** or perhaps some custom tailored listener implementation.

Comment: Do you store your OnSharedPreferencesChangedListener in a class attribute or somewhere where it keeps a reference to your listener instance? SharedPreferences-class does only keep a WeakReference to your listener. If you do not hold a reference to your listener, it will be garbage collected. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29

Comment: the class implementing OnSharedPreferencesChangedListener is a service running through whole app lifetime. I am sure its alive. Actually it is an InputMethodService. So as soon as the keyboard alive, it is also alive.

Comment: I found in the documentation, but it does support writing and reading across apps it is not clear what does it not support across multiple processes: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html  Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences does not support multiple processes.

So OnSharedPreferencesChangedListener's in App B is not get called. 
Link：http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

*Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.*

Comment: You can use the broadcast instead of a callback。

Comment: that sounds like a good solution, Listener on App A, and then App A send a Broadcast to B